# XML Parsing Performance Scala

Tags: xml, performance, scala, pattern-matching

I'm working with XML in Scala, parsing files that can reach **~20MB** in a system with **limited memory** resources. I have to read the entire file and I must extract all the data from it. Being more concrete, the nodes I have to read have finite attributes and values.

I would like to know what is the best approach in terms of performance (or if both have the same performance). I ask this because I don't know how Scala handles its XML library and I may be missing some details.

**1st approach**

```
def firstApproach(root: Elem) = 
  for { n <- root \ "node" } yield handleNodeAttribute(n)

private def handleNodeAttribute(n: Node) = n match {
  case node @ <node /> if (node \ "@attr").text == "type1" => // do something 
  // here other possible cases -> type2, type3
}
```

**2nd approach**

```
def secondApproach(root: Elem) = {
  val nodes = root \ "node"
  val type1 = filterNodesByAttribute(nodes, "attr", "type1")
  // and so on -> type2, type3
}

private def filterNodesByAttribute(nodes: NodeSeq, attr: String, value: String) = {
  nodes filter (node => (node \ ("@" + attr)) text == value)
}
```

So, is there any advantage of using XPath methods to process all the file over using pattern matching and iterating once per question (for-yield loop)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The performance of both solution is going to be similar, and neither will probably suite your memory constraints.

When we are talking about XML processing there are two types of approaches in general, **DOM** processing and **Streaming** processing.

### DOM Processing

**DOM** processing reads in the entire source document, and then allows the programmer to perform operations on the *in memory representation*. This is usually the most simple way to work the XML document from the programmers perspective, however the memory used is proportional to the size of the XML document. This means that processing large documents takes *a lot* of memory.

### Streaming Processing

**Streaming** processing reads in the XML document and processes the document on the fly as it is being read. This makes the document somewhat harder to work with from the programmers perspective, because he can not access the entire document at the same time, only a small portion. It has the advantage of having constant memory usage. That is, you don't need to have the *entire* document in memory, only the portion on which you are operating.

Given your memory constraints, you will almost certainly have to use a streaming approach. Using a streaming approach, you can read the file, extract the parts you are interested in, and then move on, thus not accumulating extra memory for the parts of the document you are not interested in.

Note, if you are extracting a *large* amount of information from the file and keeping it in memory, you will effectively negate the benefits of the streaming processing because you will just be keeping all the data in memory anyway. If you find yourself in this situation and you are having memory issues, consider streaming the data out to a file after you read it in, rather than keeping it in memory. You can think of streaming as a transformation on the XML. You read through the whole document once, transforming (keeping/changing/discarding) the parts of it you are interested, and writing them out **immediately** after the transformation is complete.

### `scala.xml`

Now, the `scala.xml` package uses a DOM style approach to XML processing, so it is probably not going to work for you. Both of your solutions are built upon this package. I would recommend interfacing with a Java library that has streaming support for XML (I don't know of any Scala ones that do).

### `javax.xml`

The Java standard library already has various tools for working with XML in a streaming manner. I have personally only used these tools for streaming based **writing** of XML files, but they should be pretty straight forward and very good for any scenario.

### Jackson

Jackson(https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) supports streaming based processing of XML, which may be more feature rich than the APIs in `javax.xml`. Make sure you use their streaming APIs, as they also have DOM based APIs, that will again, leave you with memory issues.

Comment: 20Mb is not that big nowadays. So it really depends what you are doing with the data. The only reliable way to compare your two approaches is to measure both and see how they perform.

Comment: I thought Jackson was a JSON library not an XML library?

Comment: @MichaelKay It was initially a JSON library but it now supports XML as well.

Comment: (FWIW My suggestion would be to use the SAX streaming API directly, that way you're definitely never using any of the memory-consuming APIs.)

Comment: Thanks for the information on processing XML, very useful @isomarcte. Thanks for the suggestions Imm and Michael.

Comment: By the way, @Michael Kay, look at this post: http://anti-xml.org/performance.html 20MB means a lot of memory because of the DOM processing nature.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't come across this before. It's not clear to me that doing extra work at parse time to improve search performance is a good trade-off: in Saxon I generally aim to build indexes etc. lazily on demand so you don't incur costs up-front that aren't going to give any payback later.

Comment: I updated my answer to include information about the `javax.xml` which is in the Java stdlib. It is quite good as well.